# Facebook Graph API - Getting album from "Alcohol Related" or age-restricted page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

To me this seems like it should be a relatively easy task, but I've been unable to have any success with googling for help or figuring it out on my own.

Simply put, I want to pull in a couple images from a specific photo album of a specific page onto that page's website and display them in the sidebar as "Recent Photos On Facebook" or something. This is not a personal facebook account, but a commercial page.

As an additional bit of info, this page is marked as alcohol related. How might this affect the problem and how might I get around any restrictions to the content?

I'm attempting to do this with the PHP SDK but in my attempts to pull:

```
/<page_id>/albums or
/<album_id>
```

I'm getting responses like "false" or a json value "data" that is empty.

{
   "data": []
}

here's a sample of what I'm trying to do, although I don't even know if I'm on track with this approach:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '<APPID>',
    'secret' => '<SECRET>',
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$albums = $facebook->api("/<PAGEID>/albums?access_token=".$access_token);
```

Comment: @Gazler, posted some code, but it's not much.

Comment: If this is for a user, you will need permissions to view photos.  The following url works, try using cocacola as your id in your request.  https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/albums

Comment: Gazler, another bit of information that I just realized is relevant: This page is marked as alcohol-related. This may be why I cannot just grab the album info publicly (coca-cola worked fine). What kind of workaround can be done to authenticate my website in order to grab the images?

Comment: @Brian: Try visiting the page you require while not logged into facebook.  If that is the issue then you may need to create a new facebook account and enable the offline_access permission.  With that, your access_token will be permanant and you should be able to pass that through with the request.

Comment: facebook->api automatically appends the ?access_token. no need to get it and insert inside the ->api()

Comment: @Gazler, your workaround worked out great. I basically created a dummy FB app that requested offline access, then I created a dummy FB account with a proper birthdate and authorized that app. I then use that access token (hardcoded in) to make $facebook->api calls with to get the restricted content.

If you'd like to post the solution below, I will checkmark.

@dragonjet Spot on, but in the solution Gazler described we need to specify the specific access_token since its used for offline access.

Comment: @Brian, I have posted this as a solution for future readers.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try visiting the page you require while not logged into facebook.

If that is the issue then you should create a new facebook account and enable the offline_access permission. With that, your access_token will be permanent and you should be able to pass that through with the request.

Comment: Note that the offline_access permission was removed on the 5th of December 2012: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: I have marked this as community wiki, feel free to edit this into the answer now.